# Python - SSH to list of IP addresses. Exception handling on Connection Timeout

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, connection-timeout

I am having an issue handling a timeout error in Paramiko.  Below is similar to what I am using to connect.

```
try:
    dssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    dssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    dssh.connect(IP, username, password)  
    stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('sho run')
    status = 'success'
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    status = 'fail'
```

When a host is down I get an error such as the one below and the script aborts.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh3.py", line 23, in <module>
    dssh.connect(IP, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 296, in connect
    sock.connect(addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 116] Connection timed out
```

Is there a way to catch this error and allow the script to run beginning to end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely. You just need to catch the exception that is being raised.

```
# At the beginning of your code:
import socket

# In your loop
try:
    # Your stuff
# Replace the existing exception handler:
except (socket.error, paramiko.AuthenticationException):
    status = 'fail'
```

Comment: Don't call him Shirley. Edit: I'm so sorry I just had to

Comment: This solved my issue.  I was over-thinking this one.  Thanks!